# Get datetime from given day

Tags: c#, asp.net

user just enter the day of week. For instance user enter friday. I need to find the exact date of given day and format will be like `dd.MM.yyyy`.
But I don't know how I do it.
Example:

```
label1 - Friday (entered by user)
label2 - 08.06.2012 (found by system)
```

`label1` is just a string (just Friday). It's coming from webservice as a string variable. I need to find the date and compare with today, If it's not equal or small than today I give date of upcoming Friday, else I give the date of the Friday the week after.

Comment: friday of calendar week??????

Comment: Give the user a [DateTimePicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.aspx), that way, the user can choose Friday and it will already give you the exact date of the given day. Thought this would be easier.

Comment: The day of the week is picked from a dropdown combo?

Comment: Which Friday? What is the scope?

Comment: No, it's just string. It's coming from webservice as string variable. Just Friday. And I need to find the date and compare with today, If it's not equal or small than today I give exact date, else I give next week date.

Comment: _"If it's not equal or small than today I give exact date, else I give next week date. "_ ??

Comment: I mean I compare with today and if it is not passed or small it will be first next friday. For ex: today tuesday, and you enter wednesday, compare with today, it's not pass today, we have one more day and the date will be first wednesday, it means 06.06.2012. But if you enter monday, and it's passed and the date will be first next monday which is 11.06.2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"If it's not equal or small than today I give exact date, else I give next week date. "*

Assuming that means that you return always the next date in future with the given day of week, the only exception is when **today** is the given day of week.

```
public static DateTime getNextWeekDaysDate(String englWeekDate)
{
    var desired = (DayOfWeek)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), englWeekDate);
    var current = DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek;
    int c = (int)current;
    int d = (int)desired;
    int n = (7 - c + d);

    return DateTime.Today.AddDays((n >= 7) ? n % 7 : n);
}
```

Let's test:

```
DateTime Monday   = getNextWeekDaysDate("Monday");    // 2012-06-11
DateTime Tuesday  = getNextWeekDaysDate("Tuesday");   // 2012-06-05  <-- !!! today
DateTime Wednesday= getNextWeekDaysDate("Wednesday"); // 2012-06-06
DateTime Thursday = getNextWeekDaysDate("Thursday");  // 2012-06-07
DateTime Friday   = getNextWeekDaysDate("Friday");    // 2012-06-08
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create enum of days (i.e. monday - 0, tuesday - 1, etc);
2. Get DateTime.Now DayOfWeek and cast in some way it to your enum value.
3. Calculate difference between Now.DayOfWeek and user's day of the week;
4. Use DateTime.AddDays(difference).DayofTheWeek;

Answer (score 0):

get current time with DateTime.now
Current day is DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek
Then get the day of week your user entered
Then your result is DateTime.now.AddDays( NowDayOfWeek - UserDayOfWeek).